# Propagating db changes in a network (EF core)

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework

I have quite a challenging request from a client, the client is requesting an app, this app will be distributed throughout agencies that sometimes have weak connections.

The challenge is as follows:
Each machine should be communicating with the HQ DB, however, should the connection fail all data that was supposed to be sent, needs to be stored in a local DB with up to X months of data, which will need to be synched with each workstation.

Workstation wants to save data in DB, connection is OK: No problems

Workstation wants to save data in DB, connection is lost: Data needs to be stored locally so that the app does not stop and sync this data with local network machines. When connection is restored to the HQ, all data needs to be sent to the HQ.

What I've thought so far:

- Each computer has a local DB and they store data in it, every X
  minutes data is synched throughout computers in the network (I'm
  thinking of a manually inputed list because these PCs should not
  change that often).
- Every hour a ping is sent to the HQ to see if the connection is up. If successful the data will be sent to the HQ

But they would mostly be using local DBs

This project will be done using WPF, EF Core, and the DB will be PostgreSQL.

Does anyone have any tips, insights, difficulties, etc that would help me develop the logic/architecture of this app?

Addicional information: There is 1 HQ with many Agencies, each agency has X workstations.

Comment: Maybe look into _Firebase?_ It's designed for use over a WAN, automatically synching changes that were made offline.

Comment: @MickyD I'm afraid I'd have to wotk with postgresql, but after reading up on it, Firebase would have been a great contender!

Comment: If you can setup one dedicated database server in each agency, maybe it will simplify your task by eliminating the need to sync data between workstations inside the same network. In this case you will also only need one process to sit on top of the local database and periodically attempt to push the updates into the HQ.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev that would be ideal but there will not be an agency DB, just local DBs in workstations

Comment: I would look at https://pouchdb.com/ then push the data across when you have connectivity.

Comment: Why don't you try to write in sequence to local and then to remote systematically (current and past un-synced/delayed offline data)? (instead of having to manage timers)
Additionnaly, I'm just curious (as I will have a similar case) how will you know which data has to be pushed to server once the connection is back ? (whatever re-sync strategy you have choosen)